# What is the best way to send push notification in angular webapp from mongodb?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, push-notification

I am trying to create a real-time push notification system in angular. 
The frontend needs to get these generated notifications on the browser from the unread notification data stored in mongodb. 
Is there any library to integrate this or optimum way to do this?

Note: I am trying to avoid node.js integration.

Comment: why are you trying to avoid using node ? Isn't that how you currently communicate with mongo?

Comment: No, I am not using node for mongodb connectivity. I am rather using plain MVC with mongo-java-driver. There am not against using node.js but changing the complete architecture for one feature is tough.

Comment: So use same connection path. Various ways to push notificiations are listed in link above... probably want websockets

Comment: @charlietfl I was avoiding the structure changes. But seems all the options require to have some changes or other in the current one.Server Polling too looks like an option. Will test both. Thanks!